# Understanding $\left(\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2\right) - \bar{x}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^N (x_n - \bar{x})^2$

Tags: statistics, summation

Equation 3.19 from [this document](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/54/handouts/MethodLeastSquares.pdf) claims (at the bottom of page 5) that
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2\right) - \bar{x}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^N (x_n - \bar{x})^2.
$$

I struggle to understand this. What rules were used to group $\bar{x}^2$ into the sum?

Answer (score 1):

The statement you posted is wrong.

Expand the square in the right member and find the correct one:

$$\Sigma_n[X_n-\overline{X}]^2=\Sigma_n[X_n^2-2\overline{X}X_n+\overline{X}^2]=\Sigma_nX_n^2-2\overline{X}\cdot n\overline{X}+n\overline{X}^2=\Sigma_nX_n^2-n\overline{X}^2$$

And this is exactly what the document you linked claims.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** As mentioned in the other answer, the statement is wrong, but you can easily show that the determinant is positive with the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $\sum_{k = 1}^{N} x_n y_n \le \sqrt{\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{N} x_k^2 \right)\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{N} y_k^2 \right)}$ by choosing $y_k = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of the mean $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}$, we have $N\bar{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n$. At the bottom of page $5$ :
$$\det M=\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n^2\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{N}1-\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n$$
$$=N\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}^2-\big(\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n\big)^2=N\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}^2-N^2\bar{x}^2$$ and $$\det M=N\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}^2-(N\bar{x}^2)$$
$$=N^2\big(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n^2-\bar{x}^2\big)=N^2\cdot\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n-\bar{x})^2$$
$$=N\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n-\bar{x})^2$$
So you want to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}^2-\color{red}{N}\bar{x}^2=\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n-\bar{x})^2$$

---

Indeed we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n - \bar{x})^2
=\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_{n}^2-2x_{n}\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}^2-2\bar{x}\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}+\bar{x}^2\sum_{n=1}^{N}1$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}^2-2N\bar{x}^2+N\bar{x}^2=\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n^2-N\bar{x}^2$$